# Web.config connection string works with bogus values - but why?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am stuck with the .net connection to SQL Server 2012. After reading dozens of tutorials and questions I could not find any clue. For me it seems to be too much magic going on with SQL Server.
I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web, SQL Server 2012, .net 4.5

Other people complain about NO connection with the right connection sting. But I have a database connection with a WRONG connection string. But I am not happy about it ;-)

This is my connection string with just bogus values:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionStringName" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=ThisDoesNotExist;User Id=ThisIsNoUser;Password=ThisCanNotPossiblyWork;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I run the page locally on my PC it works fine, with SQL Server Management Studio I can see that a database is created and filled properly. Where is the hidden setting for the real connection - why does it work?

And a second question in this problem sphere:

Is there a simple tutorial for a set up of SQL Server 2012 WITH user+password and WITH setting up the connection string for .net? (without using the SQL Server Management Studio: On my server SQL Server 2012 is installed but no Management Studio) I went through this procedure some weeks ago on another PC and had trouble setting the SQL Server up properly. I like explicit connection strings but was unable to understand how to do it in SQL Server 2012.

I am grateful for all hints to the right direction.

edit: I use Entity Framework. This is the code for my database context.

```
public class DBContext : DbContext
{
    public DBContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Speaker> Speakers { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

I tried editig the DBContext constructor and added a call to the base class constructor providing a connectionStingName. Now the database does not work - as wished for - because the connection string "DataBaseFirstDBEntities" was never defined :-). I'll try to go along from here with an explicit setting.

```
public DBContext()
: base("name=DataBaseFirstDBEntities")
{
}
```

The question remains: why does it work without a connection string?

Comment: How do you initialize the connection, are you using entity framework? Paste the code that makes the connection.

Comment: Almost certainly, *that* connection string is just not being used. There's no validation on connection strings per se - they can contain any nonsense if they're never used.

Comment: Do you have more than one project in the solution (for ex; class library project and an web project)? In that situation, even though you expect connection string to be read from app.config, it will be taken from web.config. That is weird, I know, I think your situation is similar.

Comment: Yes, I do use the EntityFramework. But I couldn't find anything... I don't use InitializeDatabaseConnection, and I commented out my System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<DBContext>(new MyInitializer()); some time ago. The Only projects I have is the Web project and a unit test project.

Comment: What happens when you remove that element from connection strings?

Comment: It works With empty <connectionStrings></connectionStrings>. No i am trying to use :base("name=DataBaseFirstDBEntities"). But I had no luck yet with my connection strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an explicit connection string I was able to get a "real" connection without any "magic", and this works for me:

```
public DBContext()
: base("name=DataBaseFirstDBEntities")
{
}
```

I am still confused why a connection without any setting works, but I tend to think this has to do with the Windows Authentification for the SQL Server: Since the web server process has the same user credentials as the SQL server (on my local developer machine) this seems to be a reasonable explanation.

Comment: Have you done a search of the password on the entire solution, you may find it in some machine generated code files.